# Stack overflow error when sorting an array full of equal integer values

Tags: java, stack-overflow, quicksort

I am trying to sort an array which has 100000 elements and all of them is equal.
This is my quickSort code :

```
public static void quickSortFirst(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
      int pivotIndex = partition(arr, left, right);
      quickSortFirst(arr, left, pivotIndex - 1);
      quickSortFirst(arr, pivotIndex + 1, right);
    }
  }

  private static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    int pivot = arr[left];
    int i = left + 1;
    int j = right;
    while (i <= j) {
      while (i <= j && arr[i] <= pivot) {
        i++;
      }
      while (i <= j && arr[j] > pivot) {
        j--;
      }
      if (i <= j) {
        swap(arr, i, j);
      }
    }
    swap(arr, left, j);
    return j;
  }

  private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
  }
```

It can sort 1000 and 10000 elements without any problem butt when the count of element rise it gives a stack overflow.
I tried a lot of codes I found in the internet about quicksort but none of them solve this problem.
Whenever I use 100000 elements I get overflow

Comment: [You're gonna need a bigger stack.](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/624411/youre-gonna-need-bigger-boat-jaws-line-origin)   Seriously, the more data to be sorted, the deeper the recursion gets.  At some point you will always run out of stack space. Quicksort of N elements can recurse up to N times, worst case. (In general it's more like log(N)).

Comment: How I gonna do that ?

Comment: Use the `-Xss` on the command that runs the JVM.  Though before I did that, I'd figure out the current stack size, and how deep your recursion gets before it exceeds that stack size. That might tell you whether it's even feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Whith such an algorithm and your array value (all are equal), the condition `arr[j] > pivot` will never be true and `j` never decremented.

Then the partition of a `i..j` segment will be always `i..(j-2)`, the pivot and `j`. During the recursion, the stack will grow in proportion with the array size which triggers a stack overflow.

One thing you can do is to set a threshold near `(i+j)/2+1` and decrease `j` until this threshold when all the `arr[j]` are equal. (I havn't checked the limit condition with a tiny array). This will make the pivot roughly the middle of the table, and the stack size needs in proportion to the logarithm of the array size.

Note, you will still have a stack overflow with an array which is already sorted! To avoid such a thing, you should get a pivot number randomly in the array, no always the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Your stackoverflow error could come from two possible sources:

1. It may be caused by infinite recursion
2. It may be caused by a too small stack

Your function calls are being stored in memory in a section called [the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation). First, let's understand how stacks work in general.

Stacks are collections of items (data in computer science) that are put one on the top of the other, so, the last item in this data structure has to be the first item that leaves it, of, in short, it's a [LIFO](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjvid6O8oj-AhUR57sIHVKVAecQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Ffifo-vs-lifo-approach-in-programming%2F&usg=AOvVaw1-52B9mu4DTTFLS3mQ5PNN) (Last In First Out), which is logical in view of the fact that in general, if an end-sign is not true in a function call, then two new function calls need to be added to the processing and to be evaluated before their caller.

A stack supports at least the following operations:

- push: adding a new item to the top of the stack (you are doing two pushes when you call recursively the same method)
- pop: removing an element from the top of the stack and returning its evaluation (a function execution is completed and its result is added to the caller)
- top: evaluates the top element without pulling it out from the stack

The in-memory stack is doing the stack-part of the logic automatically via handling your function call. Yet, if the issue is that your code simply used too much memory, then you need to convert your code to be iterative

[image]

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-recursion-and-iteration

So, how to convert your recursive code to work iteratively? Basically you will need a loop that runs while the stack is not empty and whenever new items are needed, push the two sides to the stack and at each step of the loop pop the top of the stack.

[Javarevisited](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/09/iterative-quicksort-example-in-java-without-recursion.html#ixzz7xdnUhvA4) gives this iterative implementation for quicksort:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Java Program to implement Iterative QuickSort Algorithm, without recursion.
 *
 * @author WINDOWS 8
 */
public class Sorting {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] unsorted = {34, 32, 43, 12, 11, 32, 22, 21, 32};
        System.out.println("Unsorted array : " + Arrays.toString(unsorted));

        iterativeQsort(unsorted);
        System.out.println("Sorted array : " + Arrays.toString(unsorted));
    }


    /*
     * iterative implementation of quicksort sorting algorithm.
     */
    public static void iterativeQsort(int[] numbers) {
        Stack stack = new Stack();
        stack.push(0);
        stack.push(numbers.length);

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            int end = stack.pop();
            int start = stack.pop();
            if (end - start < 2) {
                continue;
            }
            int p = start + ((end - start) / 2);
            p = partition(numbers, p, start, end);

            stack.push(p + 1);
            stack.push(end);

            stack.push(start);
            stack.push(p);

        }
    }

    /*
     * Utility method to partition the array into smaller array, and
     * comparing numbers to rearrange them as per quicksort algorithm.
     */
    private static int partition(int[] input, int position, int start, int end) {
        int l = start;
        int h = end - 2;
        int piv = input[position];
        swap(input, position, end - 1);

        while (l < h) {
            if (input[l] < piv) {
                l++;
            } else if (input[h] >= piv) {
                h--;
            } else {
                swap(input, l, h);
            }
        }
        int idx = h;
        if (input[h] < piv) {
            idx++;
        }
        swap(input, end - 1, idx);
        return idx;
    }

    /**
     * Utility method to swap two numbers in given array
     *
     * @param arr - array on which swap will happen
     * @param i
     * @param j
     */
    private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }

}
```

Another possible problem is that you ended up having an infinite recursion that failed to detect that the algorithm fulfilled its purpose and kept on pushing function calls to the stack until the function calls have overflown the stack's limits. In such cases you will need to thoroughly check the end-signs of your recursion and see whether everything was well-implemented, if this is an issue in your case, then you might end up concluding that you need to change a `<=` condition to `<` or something of the like. We know that the height of the call tree is log2(n) and if n = 100000, then this height is of 16.61, which does not seem to be terribly deep.